# Failed to create virtual environment directory in cmd

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-venv

Unable to create venv using python 3x;

`python -m venv myclub`

**Error: Command '['C:\Users\Sibasankar Panigrahi\myclub\Scripts\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be caused by how you installed Python.

Uninstall and reinstall, using the 'all users' option in the custom / advanced menu options of the installer. Don't forget to tick add to path!.

Comment: yeah. i have added to the path